# GRUB says Error 13: Invalid or unsupported executable format

Tags: kernel

I wrote a kernel. Here is my kernel start up file:

```
.text
    .globl start
start:
jmp main

mboot:
 .set ALIGN,    1<<0
.set MEMINFO,  1<<1
.set FLAGS,    ALIGN | MEMINFO
.set MAGIC,    0x1BADB002
.set CHECKSUM, -(MAGIC + FLAGS)

.section multiboot
.align 4
.long MAGIC
.long FLAGS 
.long CHECKSUM
main:
call kernel_main
    cli
    hlt
```

Here is my first C file:

```
void print(char *message, int line,int ch){
     char *vm=(char *)0xb8000;
     int i=(line*80*2);
     i=i+(ch*2);
     while(*message!=0){
     if (*message=='\n'){line++;
     i=(line*80*2);}
     else {vm[i]=*message;
     i++;
     vm[i]=0x07;
     i++;} *message++;}}
```

Based on that I wrote a second C file:

```
#include "ESfunctions.c" //this is the previous C file 
kernel_main(){
print("Hi!\nHow do you like my OS?",0,0);}
```

Edit: Here is my linker script:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary")
ENTRY(start)
SECTIONS
{
  .text  0x100000 : {
    code = .; _code = .; __code = .;
    *(.text)
    . = ALIGN(4096);
  }
  .data  : {
    data = .; _data = .; __data = .;
    *(.data)
    . = ALIGN(4096);
  }
  .bss  :
  {
    bss = .; _bss = .; __bss = .;
    *(.bss)
    . = ALIGN(4096);
  }
  end = .; _end = .; __end = .;
}
```

Edit: I am not using a cross-compiler. I am using gcc on Ubuntu.

I compiled the C code and assembled the assembly code and linked them together. Then I turned it into a bootable image and together with grub I burned it all onto a disc. After grub started I entered the command "kernel KERNEL.BIN" (KERNEL.BIN is my kernel) and grub said "Error 13: Invalid or unsupported executable format. What is wrong? Can anybody help me?

Comment: Checked the grub code and the error string is ERR_EXEC_FORMAT. There are a couple of reasons to return that error so you will need to read the grub source code and check your boot image to locate the exact issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing your linker script or Makefile (please attach them) we can only guess at what might be wrong.

Please check the following:

- You are using a cross-compiler that compiles machine code for the correct target, leaves out system-specific library files, and uses the right binary format (I would recommend ELF).
- The GRUB magic number is within the first 8KiB of the kernel. Make sure the linker script puts the multiboot header section first, before any other code.

I would have made this a comment rather than an answer, but I don't have enough reputation yet.